# Collapse certain columns horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have:

```
haves = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['R123','R234'],
                        'Price':[1.18,0.23],
                        'CS_Medium':[1, 0],
                        'CS_Small':[0, 1],
                        'SC_A':[1,0],
                        'SC_B':[0,1],
                        'SC_C':[0,0]})
print(haves)
```

[image]

given a list of columns, like so:

```
list_of_starts_with = ["CS_", "SC_"]
```

I would like to arrive here:

```
wants = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['R123','R234'],
                        'Price':[1.18,0.23],
                        'CS':['Medium', 'Small'],
                        'SC':['A', 'B'],})

print(wants)
```

[image]

I am aware of `wide_to_long` but don't think it is applicable here?

Comment: wide_to_long not work here

Comment: I am sorry I would not know how in this case given a list of columns with their start string - see list_of_starts_with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the list of columns (assuming the `starts_with` is enough to identify them), it is possible to do the changes in bulk:

```py
def preprocess_column_names(list_of_starts_with, column_names):
    "Returns a list of tuples (merged_column_name, options, columns)"
    columns_to_transform = []
    for starts_with in list_of_starts_with:
        len_of_start = len(starts_with)
        columns = [col for col in column_names if col.startswith(starts_with)]
        options = [col[len_of_start:] for col in columns]
        merged_column_name = starts_with[:-1]  # Assuming that the last char is not needed
        columns_to_transform.append((merged_column_name, options, columns))
    return columns_to_transform


def merge_columns(df, merged_column_name, options, columns):
    for col, option in zip(columns, options):
        df.loc[df[col] == 1, merged_column_name] = option
    return df.drop(columns=columns)

def merge_all(df, columns_to_transform):
    for merged_column_name, options, columns in columns_to_transform:
        df = merge_columns(df, merged_column_name, options, columns)
    return df
```

And to run:

```py
columns_to_transform = preprocess_column_names(list_of_starts_with, haves.columns)
wants = merge_all(haves, columns_to_transform)
```

If your column names are not surprising (such as `Index_` being in `list_of_starts_with`) the above code should solve the problem with a reasonable performance.

Comment: I have lots of columns ... so not practical. thanks.

Comment: And are all your columns named `<name>_<option>`? And is this pattern enough to identify all columns you want to combine?

Comment: yes - sorry I edited question and added list_of_starts_with = ["CS_", "SC_"]

Comment: thanks - this is amazing! thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

We could convert "SC" and "CS" column values to boolean mask to filter the column names; then `join` it back to the original DataFrame:

```
msk = haves.columns.str.contains('_')
s = haves.loc[:, msk].astype(bool)
s = s.apply(lambda x: dict(s.columns[x].str.split('_')), axis=1)
out = haves.loc[:, ~msk].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index))
```

Output:

```
  Product  Price      CS SC
0    R123   1.18  Medium  A
1    R234   0.23   Small  B
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert the data to a long form, filter for rows that have a value of 1, then convert back to wide form. We can use `pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor` for the wide to long part, and `pivot` to return to wide form:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
( haves
.pivot_longer(index=["Product", "Price"], 
              names_to=("main", "other"), 
              names_sep="_")
.query("value==1")
.pivot(index=["Product", "Price"], 
       columns="main", 
       values="other")
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index()
)

  Product  Price      CS SC
0    R123   1.18  Medium  A
1    R234   0.23   Small  B
```

You can totally avoid `pyjanitor`, by tranforming on the columns before reshaping (it still involves wide to long, then long to wide):

```py
index = [col for col in haves 
        if not col.startswith(tuple(list_of_starts_with))]
temp = haves.set_index(index)

temp.columns = (temp
                .columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
                .set_names(["main", "other"])

# reshape to get final dataframe
(temp
.stack(["main", "other"])
.loc[lambda df: df == 1]
.reset_index("other")
.drop(columns=0)
.unstack()
.droplevel(0, 1)
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index()
)

  Product  Price      CS SC
0    R123   1.18  Medium  A
1    R234   0.23   Small  B
```

Comment: thanks. I suppose instead of using ["Product", "Price"] one could also use something using ~list_of_starts_with?

Comment: yea, technically you could, made an edit